# Is there any solution to do the "NOT IN" functionality in Elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, lucene, aggregation, logstash

Here is a simple but difficult question.
I want to do an aggregation for a query results that should be use **"NOT IN"** functionality like any RDBMS' SQL.

For example, I want to do a job something like below.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                !!! Documents whose 'user_id' field value is 'NOT IN' distinct user_ids where the 'action' field value is 'signup' !!!
            }
        }
    }, 
    "aggregations": {
        "distinct_users":{
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "user_id",
                "precision_threshold": 1000000
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

## Edit

Here is an example data.

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1' -d'{ "user_id": 1234, "action": "signup" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/2' -d'{ "user_id": 1234, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/3' -d'{ "user_id": 1234, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/4' -d'{ "user_id": 5678, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/5' -d'{ "user_id": 5678, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/6' -d'{ "user_id": 9012, "action": "signup" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/7' -d'{ "user_id": 9012, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/8' -d'{ "user_id": 9012, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/9' -d'{ "user_id": 3456, "action": "visit" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/10' -d'{ "user_id": 3456, "action": "visit" }'
```

What I really want to get is the "Documents whose user_id DOES NOT signed up based on these log data".
So, documents [**4, 5, 9, 10**] are the final results what I want to get.

Is it possible to get the results what I want in Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. Can you give some examples with sample data (or real data) of what you are trying to achieve? Maybe there is another way, or you are looking at the problem from a RDBMS angle. But, as you described the issue now, I don't think you can use the cardinality aggregation to filter inside a query some documents.

Comment: If you really want to use cardinality output to filter documents, I believe you need to queries: one gets the distinct users, the other uses the result from the cardinality.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks Andrei Stefan. I edited my question with some example data.

Comment: I still don't think there is any way with how you have the documents organized. Elasticsearch is not good at using the results of a query to perform some filtering *in the same single query*. There are situations where things might work, but not in your particular case imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, elasticsearch does not do joins and what you are asking for is a variation of a join.

As pointed out above, it does have parent child relations and nested objects though which might help you somewhat, depending on your domain.

Elasticsearch also does not have a distinct feature which you need as well. But you can sort of fake it with a terms aggregation.

However, that does not help you here since you really need a join for this. So, the only solution here is to do the join outside of elasticsearch. Depending on your data size, that might be expensive. Also see [application side joins](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html).

Answer (score -1):

if you use the [not filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-filter.html) Elasticsearch will check each document in turn - the following will return **all** documents that have an action where `action` is anything but `signup`.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/myindex/my_type/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
           "not" : {
            "term" : { "action" : "signup" }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

To meet the requirement where a userid is returned if it doesn't have any instances of `action=signup` then you'll need to set up a [parent child relationship](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html).

in this case, Userid would be unique across all `user` type documents. Each user document would have one or more `action` type children.

The following query checks the `action` child and returns the `user` document.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/my_type/_search?pretty' -d '{
 "query": {
   "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "not" : {
       "has_child": { "type": "my_action", "term" : { "action" : "signup" }}
      }
    }
   }  
 }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the thing what I want to get is a little different. In my case, same user_id can appears multiple times. I want to filtered out user_ids which appears with 'action' value 'signup' within a same document at least once, so that documents that have the user_id are filtered out altogether.

Comment: I understand the problem better now - I think you may need to re-organise your data. E.g. make the action field a child document of the user document.